# Ubuntu 16.04 - NVidia GTX 860M and OpenGL SL 4.5?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opengl

I'm using Ubuntu only to learn the OpenGL SL programming. I was on Debian version but I got a big problem and I'm tired to solve them (sometime just with an update).

Whatever ... Now I'm on Ubuntu and I would like to use all the power of my GPU.

```
~$ glxinfo | grep "version"

GLX version: 1.4
Max core profile version: 3.3
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

So, **I can only develop under GLSL 3.3 while the GPU can use GLSL 4.5**.
(http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-860m/specifications).

I tried a lot of differents install (NVidia, xserver, free or not, ...) and I wonder if there is an solution.

**Is there a means to develop with OpenGL SL 4.5 on Ubuntu with the GPU NVidia GTX 860m ?**

(As this GPU use the Optimus, I installed Bumblebee.)

Thanks in advance,